# how the asm calls in C code are tested for coverage?

Tags: testing, assembly, verification

I am working on a project involving ARM assembly. I would like to know whether the code coverage tools will also cover the in line assembly involved as **asm** **volatile** ( /* The assembly code goes here*/ ); .It would help if some one who has written Test Cases and Test Procedures to test assembly code share their experience. 
In my project they are using Rapita tool. Some in my project have used Vector Cast previously. In both cases the assembly coverage is not there it seems. Thats why I am interested to know about it

Comment: To be able to at least give any answer one would need to know what tools you are talking about.

Comment: Of course, it differs, because assembly isn't part of standard C. Which code coverage tools are you interested in?

Comment: Too general of a question, you would need to talk about specific compilers and specific coverage tools.   And/or take a few seconds create a coverage problem in inline assembly, and see if your coverage tool catches it.

Comment: Why would it matter? Assuming that your tools work at the level of functions (which as far as I'm aware, most do), then inline assembly would not change anything. It would just be code that executes in the context of a particular function. It would only matter if your code coverage tools had instruction-level granularity, which I think would be prohibitively noisy. Not to mention somewhat fragile.

Comment: In my project they are using Rapita tool. Some in my project have  used Vector Cast previously. In both cases the assembly coverage is not there it seems. Thats why I am interested to know about it .